# How to deploy an unmanaged version of EDA

Tags: education-data-architecture

## [Article on EDA as unmanaged package](https://powerofus.force.com/s/article/EDA-Managed-Unmanaged-Package-Considerations)

As mentioned above, there is a way in case of demand for deploying unmanaged version of EDA.
While after several tries, I still can NOT work out steps to take.
Have anyone ever successfully deployed an unmanaged version in your Org?

Comment: Note: the article referenced above has been removed by the Salesforce.org documentation team, as it contained a number of inaccuracies and was not intended to be published.

Answer (score 1):

*I am a member of the Salesforce.org Release Engineering team supporting EDA*.

First, emphasizing the critical point: installing EDA unmanaged is completely unsupported and for most use cases is very unwise. You will not receive EDA updates, you are not eligible for support from Salesforce (cases you open will be closed), and you won't be able to use any other ISV products that depend on EDA. Installing EDA unmanaged is typically only for persons who are developing EDA itself.

If you decide you must do this, [CumulusCI](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/) is the recommended route. CumulusCI is Salesforce.org's product for scratch org-based automation on top of Salesforce DX and is used to build and install EDA and other products.

After installing CumulusCI and cloning the EDA repository, you would need to set up a Dev Hub to build a scratch org, or use the `cci org connect` command to link to a persistent org.

If you are installing in a persistent org, you will have to turn on the required features Translation Workbench and Chatter before you begin installing. You will likely also need to remove the `featureParameters` subdirectory, as Feature Parameters will be non-functional and may not deploy.

Then, to achieve a minimal installation, you'd execute the commands

```
cci flow run dependencies --org <your org>
cci flow run deploy_unmanaged --org <your org>
cci task run deploy_post --org <your org>
```

This will do no configuration whatsoever; it merely installs the product unmanaged, including its required unpackaged elements such as Record Types. You may need to do extensive configuration to achieve a usable EDA configuration. Again, *this is not supported in any way for production use*.

For a more comprehensive *development* environment, you would do

```
cci flow run dev_org --org <your org>
```

Note that the configuration executed by a development environment may not be suitable for other use cases.

---

Again, unless you are planning to do development on EDA itself, I *strongly* recommend you reconsider. Using EDA unmanaged in a production org is likely to be a very costly choice in the long run.

I will also note that this article creates a mistaken impression that installing EDA as a managed package might alter the org's code coverage level. This is not true, and I am working with our internal teams to have this corrected.

Comment: Thanks, but  still there are issues or errors similar to what I came across when I tried to "push source to scratch org" based on repository cloned from Github EDA. Error message runs like "Update of ApexClass ADDR_CannotDelete_TEST: Error on line 402, col 9: Variable does not exist: addrsWithChildRecords"

Comment: Continued from previous comment, My attention goes to this message when run "cci flow run deploy_unmanaged --org" as you advised, stated as “2021-05-02 17:56:13: Stripping namespace tokens from metadata for unmanaged deployment”, Look like the cci command is doing something inside for purpose of installing EDA as "unmanaged",. But I am just wondering whether the cci command is powerful enough to install as "unmanaged" just clone from Git repository and run this command line. Are there anything else what we need do? E.g. modify or remove namespace within project configuration file.

Comment: To resolve issues 
**1) change language to Eng from CHN (No such object translation xml for CHN)**  
**2) Add RecordTypeId in Account.cls and ensure 1 Record Type in Org**
**3) Remove namespace in project conf file**.

 After such changes made, I can successfully `SFDX Push source to scratch org`. I still can NOT find "EDA" from App launcher (Apex classes uploaded successfully as verified in Org). Finally I followed advised step again to `run cci flow run deploy_unmanaged --org`, i GOT another problem - _"limit for the number of feature parameters (25)"_; **ANY IDEA or WORKAROUND???**

Comment: @samuelywong CumulusCI is the official build tool for EDA. If you ran the commands I gave you, you would not need to use "Push Source" or manually create a Record Type, as both are handled by CumulusCI. You also do not need to remove the namespace in the project file if you follow the instructions above.

Comment: In a scratch org, the feature parameters should deploy cleanly. It sounds like they probably did deploy cleanly the first time and are now failing on subsequent deployment attempts. I still don't really understand what you are seeking to achieve, though.

Comment: Exactly as your advise, clone from github>>`cci org connect <the org id>` and then run the 3 cci commands as you listed, still error come like "Update of Translations en_GB: Error: Not available for deploy for this organization".

Comment: Also prompt on limit for feature parameters;
Pretty sure I am doing exactly same as advised, no idea where I got things wrong

Comment: I've amended my answer above to cover some more of these edge cases.

Comment: I _really, strongly recommend_ you work in a scratch org. You should in no way be doing this on your production Salesforce org, and a persistent org is not a good location to be doing development or exploration on this product.

Comment: All is fine, THANK YOU VERY MUCH....except below:
By running `cci task run deploy_post --org <your org>`, I still cannot see EDA from App launcher, while this one can be fixed by running instead `cci flow run config_dev --org <your org>`

Comment: As I noted above, `dev_org` (including `config_dev`) does lots of configuration _for a development use case_. Otherwise, you need to permission yourself. The development configuration is likely not to be suitable for a non-development org, but I still don't know what it is you're trying to do with your org.

Comment: The exploration begin just for checking to what extent EDA is available for re-developing as I just happen to find some class files are not allowed for editing or alike after installing via online installer for EDA

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [installer](https://install.salesforce.org/products/eda). Simply log in and click install. I tested this in my org, it was just a few steps and takes only a few minutes. As long as you're an administrator, it should work just fine.

Comment: The installer only delivers EDA as a managed package.